# Windows batch file not running when double clicked

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two Windows batch file. Both work when called from command prompt. Only one of the two run runs when double clicked. How come?

The following script (named CopyToStation9.bat) runs with a double-click:

```
@echo off

for /R "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX" %%f in (*.csv) do copy "%%f" "\\192.168.0.10\c\X"
```

The following script (named CleanUp.bat) doesn't run with a double-click

```
@echo off
set delFileList=.\test\
for %%A in (%delFileList%) do (
    del /Q %%A
    echo file %%A  deleted
)
```

Comment: What are their names?

Comment: Can you show the scripts?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Add `pause` command as very last line of `CleanUp.bat`; I think it should run on a double-click…

Comment: John - How about making the `set delFileList=.\test\<filename>.txt` like so, etc. and make it point to an actual file for the filelist, and then perhaps using `for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%delFileList%") do (` to ensure the file list **path** or **filename** or **list values** can handle spaces if it has any then this should then work more reliably than what you have I would think but I'd also change `del /q %%A` to be `DEL /Q /F "%%~A"`... Give that a shot and then report back your results and if that works, I'll then be glad to add this as an answer with further detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are try to use a UNC path, try using `pushd`and `popd`.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013941/how-to-run-batch-file-from-network-share-without-unc-path-are-not-supported-me